Asynchronous user input not being stored
I am working on a project in CodeHS using Javascript. I am trying to collect user input a number of times through a loop. However, I want this input to be asynchronous because readInt is a blocking function and will prevent the following code from being executed until the input popup is finished.
Because of this, I have tried to use the readIntAsync function, which allegedly allows the user to input values without the appearance of the popup box and without the blocking of the following code. However, when I do this, the computer does not appear to store the user input.
For example, in the following code (not from my program), the circle never moves.


var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var circle = new Circle(50);
circle.setPosition(x, y);
add(circle);

async function start() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var begin = await readIntAsync("Pick a number. ");
    println(begin);
    x += begin * 50;
    y += begin * 50;
    circle.setPosition(x, y);
    add(circle);
  }
}
start();
<script src="https://cdn.codehs.com/chs-js-lib/0.2.21/dist/chs.iife.js"></script>



Is there a way to store the input from an asynchronous input function (readLineAsync, readIntAsync, readBooleanAsync, readFloatAsync). Alternatively, is there another way to get non-blocking input that will be stored?

Where does readIntAsync() come from?

@Phil https://codehs.com/tutorial/andy/asynchronous-input

Where do you expect it to 'store' the user input?

@qrsngky I expect that when that variable is used, the value that was input by the user will be used.

Well, the code (as it is now) is already using the value that was input by the user. Every time, x increases by 50 times of the number that was input,  and so does y.

At first x=50 and y=50, then if you input 1, x+=1*50 so the new value of x is the old value +50, similarly with y. So after the first iteration x=100 and y=100. If you input 1 again, x=150 and y=150, etc.

@qrsngky But it doesn't do that, because the circle doesn't move.

It does not do it here, but it does in that other webpage. The circle moves after you type 1 and press enter
